# Center Footer in Middle of page

Tags: html, css, footer

I am having trouble centering my footer () in the center of my page. I was able to get it to stay on the bottom of the page, but not center it.

I added `left: 50%` to the #footer, but the aligned it too far to the right. Also the `<hr>` tag is only running the span of the text beneath it. When I took it out of the div it was floating in the middle of the page. Any ideas on how I can center this (preferably using %, since I will be embedding it in another page which has different alignment settings).

Here is a link: http://jsbin.com/fajosekosu/2/edit

Your input is much apprecatied.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left: 50%;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black; 
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

a:hover {
    color: white;
}

</style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Footer</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/LESSON5/5_Signup_CSS.css">

</head>
<body>

    <div id="footer">
    <hr>
    <footer>
        <a href="/LESSON5/1%20-%20LOGIN.php">Login</a>
        <a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create Account</a>
        <a href="/LESSON5/3%20-%20HOMEPAGE%20:%20WELCOME.php">Homepage</a>
        <a href="/LESSON5/4%20-%20LOGOUT%20PAGE.PHP">Logout</a>
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to footer css

```
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin-left to bring it back from 50% left. Just add this to your footer:

```
margin-left: -190px;
left: 50%;
```

190 being half the width of your footer.

Really though, a better way to go about this process though is to fix your footer container and wrap the elements inside it in a div. Make that div an inline-block and center that. Also, your footer element should be the wrapper element.

HTML:

```
  <footer>
    <div class="footer-contents">
    <hr>
        <a href="/LESSON5/1%20-%20LOGIN.php">Login</a>
        <a href="/LESSON5/2%20-%20CREATE%20AN%20ACCOUNT.php">Create Account</a>
        <a href="/LESSON5/3%20-%20HOMEPAGE%20:%20WELCOME.php">Homepage</a>
        <a href="/LESSON5/4%20-%20LOGOUT%20PAGE.PHP">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer {
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}

.footer-contents{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Where did you get a fixed width?

Comment: It's half his footer width

Comment: Where is the footer width specified?

Comment: Updated with better answer.

Answer (score 0):

In #footer add:

```
     left:0;
     right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
width: 100%;
```

to your `#footer` rule:

http://jsbin.com/guxovaloci/2/edit?html,css,output

Alternatively, if you want a specified width other than `100%`, use

```
left: 0;
right: 0;
```